# pdf uplaoded using multer unable to be dawnloaded in the react frontend even if its displaied

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

[image]  <a href={`http://localhost:6500/${data.Document_path}`} download>{data.Document}

// error message on browser :Cannot GET /Resources/fileFromPhd/1683165623853_1642425612.pdf

the path name and file path is coming to the react frontend perfectly and also express status folder setup for Resource is setted correctly, for image its working but for pdf dawnload its not working.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: its 404 actually, the thing is the pdf file is uploaded using Multer and i can call it to the frontend and everything like file path and file name but using the file path and file name it cant be downloaded. i prepared a static express and doing that helped for the image but the pdf is still not working for dawnload.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved just by passing the document name instead of the path and preparing an express static file serving middleware for accessing the files at the backend

{data.Document_name}